# sending a struct with MapViewOfFile and reading an unknown value

Tags: c++, c, winapi, kernel

I am basically trying to cast or copy my struct to my other process section view but I keep getting an error

> C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'declaration'

This is what I am doing:

```
type RPM(UINT_PTR ReadAddress)
{
    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return {};
    }

    DWORD64 Bytes;
    KM_READ_REQUEST ReadRequest{};

    type response{};

    ReadRequest.ProcessId = PID;
    ReadRequest.Address = ReadAddress;
    ReadRequest.Size = sizeof(type);
    ReadRequest.Output = &response;
```

The problem is here:

```
auto pBuf = (ReadRequest)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 4096);
if (!pBuf)
{
    printf("OpenFileMappingA(write) fail! Error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    system("pause");
}

printf("MapViewOfFile(write) created ! \n");
```

I am having another problem trying to read an unknown value from my kernel driver. It basically reads memory and then changes that value to another thing based on what I am reading from if its int, float, etc..

```
PKM_READ_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKM_READ_REQUEST)SharedSection; // cast readRequest to our struct which is in SharedSection.
void* ReadOutput = ReadInput->Output;

Status = ReadKernelMemory(Process, ReadInput->Address, ReadOutput, ReadInput->Size);
```

I am trying to copy it to my shared section so I can read it from user mode, but idk how to cast it or what the value would be.

```
memcpy(SharedSection, &ReadOutput, sizeof(ReadOutput));
```

This is how I want to try to read it, but cast it as the same way because I don't want to read it as void, I want to read it as the value that was given from my kernel mode.

```
auto pBuf = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 4096);
if (!pBuf)
{
    printf("OpenFileMappingA(write) fail! Error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    system("pause");
}

printf("MapViewOfFile(write) created ! \n");
```

BTW, I am using the un-documented function `mmcopyvirtualmemory` in my kernel driver.

Comment: `MapViewOfFile` returns a pointer (`void*`). You can't cast it to a non-pointer type. I'd suggest you should learn about pointers and other basic language features before moving on to writing a kernel driver using undocumented functions.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter thanks for pointing that out am learning c++ , but am having problems with pointers could you link any useful tutorial or good documentation about pointer arithmetic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

`auto pBuf = (ReadRequest)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 4096);`

The `ReadRequest` is not a type but an object, If you want to write the file map address as the struct `KM_READ_REQUEST`, you should convert the return pointer to the type of `PKM_READ_REQUEST`, and also take the control of the size of file map:

```
auto pBuf = (PKM_READ_REQUEST)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(KM_READ_REQUEST));
```

So that you can set the `PID`,`Address`,`Size` and `Output` for it.

2.

```
memcpy(SharedSection, &ReadOutput, sizeof(ReadOutput));
```

- `ReadOutput` is already the address of output value, So you don't
  need the operation `&`.
- Sizeof(a pointer) is always equal to 4(in    32-bit) and 8(in
  64-bit);
- You'd better use a new variable to store copied values, Instead of overwriting previous data。

So

```
type new_var;
memcpy(&new_var, ReadOutput, sizeof(KM_READ_REQUEST));
```

EDIT: Answer your comments,

You can set a single Event to communicate between driver and UM.

App:

```
hDevice = CreateFile(Device);
hEvent = CreateEvent(...);
DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_SET_EVENT, &hEvent,...);
WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
```

Driver:

```
case IOCTL_SET_EVENT:
{
    HANDLE hUserEvent = *(HANDLE *)pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    status = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(hUserEvent, EVENT_MODIFY_STATE,*ExEventObjectType, KernelMode, (PVOID*)&pDevExt->pEvent, NULL);
    ObDereferenceObject(pDevExt->pEvent);
    break;
}
```

Then set event:

```
KeSetEvent(pdx->pEvent,...);
```

Comment: thank you however i have some questions if you mind answering them 1- now i read that i really don't need to map the section view more than 1 time , the question is that var auto pBuf is shared between the 2 sections so i can either over write it or create a new one with MapViewOfFile every time i need a new var and the other question is , i want to create a mutex between my driver and UM to notify that the operation has succeed so i can read ReadOutput into my read memory function how could i go about doing that , could you leave a Pseudocode thank you +rep