# how to use MapViewOfFile when sending a struct

Tags: c++, windows, api, kernel

I have already asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090976/sending-a-struct-with-mapviewoffile-and-reading-an-unknown-value)

But I still can't understand how `MapViewOfFile`  works. I have seen the msdn example but am still confused.
I just need someone to explain to me how I could send a whole struct to my shared section and read it from there.
Also how does `MapViewOfFile`  actually works with sending and reading vars from it.

But most importantly how could I send a whole struct after it got initialized from process 1 to process 2 (you could see what I am talking about in my old thread that I have linked above).

Comment: It's not being sent anywhere. The memory is physically mapped into the address space of multiple processes at the same time.

Comment: @drescherjm but how would you access it from the other process, all i know for now is i need to use memcpy to copy a var from process a to process b for example. but how would you access it from process b ? and how would you send it from process a i need some code examples to understand more about this.

Comment: @Frankoo Both processes have to call `MapViewOfFile()` to map the same memory mapping object from `CreateFileMapping()`. You have to give the mapping object a unique name so both processes can share the same mapping object. Then both processes will have mapped pointers to the same physical data in memory.  This is clearly explained and demonstrated in Microsoft's documentation. What are you having trouble understanding about it exactly?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau good but lets say for example i have a struct and i have initialized it with my object then i just need to send a pointer to my struct and it will have all of the data filled in it ?

Comment: @Frankoo Process A creates a named mapping object, maps a view of it to get a pointer to physical memory, and populates that memory with data as needed. Process B opens the same mapping object by name, maps its own view of it to get a pointer to physical memory, and reads the data from that memory as needed. You can't send a pointer from A to B, pointers can't cross process boundaries. You have to copy the struct data into memory that both A and B can access using their own local pointers.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau thank you , but the thing that i want to understand is if i mapped my struct pointer to process b then for ex : (PKM_READ_REQUEST) it will have a pid,address etc.. i just need to map (PKM_READ_REQUEST) and use it like memcpy(pBuf,PKM_READ_REQUEST,sizeof(PKM_READ_REQUEST)) then i will just have it there ? with all info filled in then i can just do something like this . Code "PKM_READ_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKM_READ_REQUEST)SharedSection; 
" well that even works ?

Comment: You need to stop thinking of it as "sending" it to the other process. You don't send anything. Both processes obtain their own view of the same chunk of memory. One process writes to that memory, the other process reads from it.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter well , i just want to know how could i access it from the other process see the comment below i have wrote what i want to do.

Comment: Once it's mapped into memory you access it by reading the memory, like you do any other memory. You could cast a pointer to the mapped memory and read from it directly or use `memcpy` to copy the memory into a local structure. It's just memory.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter thank you for explaining it to me , i give you my respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either copy the structure, or simply allocate it and share it. Both apps can share the structure using the following:

```
typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
} MYSTRUCT;

auto hMap = CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0,
                sizeof(MYSTRUCT), "MyStructShareName");
MYSTRUCT* pMyStruct = (MYSTRUCT*) MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ |
                 FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

At this point both apps have a pointer to the exact same memory via *pMyStruct*.

Comment: Just an FYI, you should be using the predefined `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead of hard-coding `(HANDLE) -1`. Even the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) says to use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: @Randolph and say for example i had initialized an object that does write to my struct so it saves it there and when i (share) my struct then in the other process it can just get a pointer to that struct  and just use it ? this is what i mean `type RPM(UINT_PTR ReadAddress)
{
    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return {};
    }

    DWORD64 Bytes;
    KM_READ_REQUEST ReadRequest{};

    type response{};

    ReadRequest.ProcessId = PID;
    ReadRequest.Address = ReadAddress;
    ReadRequest.Size = sizeof(type);
    ReadRequest.Output = &response;`